# Calculating a double integral over a bounded closed region

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the double integral
$\iint_D \frac{y+x\ln x}{xy^2}dxdy$ where $D$ is the area bounded by
$y=\ln x, 3y=\ln x, y=-x+4, y=-x+2$.

Well, let's change variables $u=x+y, v=\frac{y}{\ln x}$
So we move from $D$ to a new region called $D'$,

$D'=\{(u,v): 2\leq u \leq 4, 1/3 \leq v \leq 1\}$.

Then

$$J=\frac{1}
{ \left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\-y/x(\ln x)^2 & 1/\ln x
\end{matrix}\right|}
=\frac{1}{1/\ln x+y/x(\ln x)^2}$$

However I did not manage to write $J$ in terms of $u,v$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Right in between the change of variable and the rename of variable, your integral would be

\begin{split}
\int\int \frac{y + x\ln(x)}{xy^2} \cdot J  & = \int \int \frac{y + x\ln(x)}{xy^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1/\ln x+y/x(\ln x)^2}  \\\\
& = \int\int \frac{y + x\ln(x)}{xy^2}\cdot \frac{x\ln^2(x)}{x\ln(x) + y} 
\\\\
& = \int\int \frac{\ln^2(x)}{y^2}
\\\\
& = \int\int \frac{1}{u^2}
\end{split}

Comment: Thanks! Or I can sy that I am finding the function $f(u,v)$ satisfying $f(x,y)=f(u,v) |J|$ right? @Laplacian